# Is Hatcher's proof of thom isomorphism theorem flawed?: I don't believe that $H^n(E,E_0)\cong H^n(R^n,R^n-0)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes

Let $E$ be an oriented vector bundle over $B$, a CW complex, with fiber of dimension $n$.  Let $E_0$ be $E - B\times 0$. The main theorem Hatcher uses to prove the thom isomorphism theorem is that the restriction map $H^n(E,E_0) \to H^n(R^n,R^n-0)$ is an isomorphism.

But here is a counter example:  Let $E=S^2 \times R^2$.  Being a trivial bundle it is oriented.  We have $H^2(E,E_0)=H^2(S^2 \times (D^2, S^1))=\tilde H^2(S^2 \times (D^2, S^1))=\tilde H^2(S^2 \times S^2)=H^2(S^2 \times S^2) =\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

But $H^2(R^2,R^2-0)=Z$.  So there cannot be an isomorphism between $H^2(R^2,R^2-0)$ and $H^2(E,E_0)$.

What is wrong?

Comment: What is $E_0$? The $0$-section of the bundle?

Comment: $E_0$ is the sphere bundle of $E$.

Comment: I edited the question and put the definition of $E_0$.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your mistake is in the equality $\tilde{H}^2(S^2 \times (D^2, S^1)) = \tilde{H}^2(S^2 \times S^2)$ you wrote. It might be a bit easier to see why this is false in one dimension lower. Consider the trivial bundle $S^1 \times D^1 \to S^1$ instead. In the proof you would consider $(S^1 \times D^1, S^1 \times S^0)$, and it might be tempting to write $H^1(S^1 \times (D^1, S^0)) = H^1(S^1 \times S^1)$.

But this is false! When you look at the quotient $(S^1 \times D^1) / (S^1 \times S^0)$ (which you implicitly do), this is not a torus. You collapse *all* the boundary to one point, and so you get a torus with the whole inner circle collapsed, or equivalently a 2-sphere with two points identified. And the first cohomology group of this is $\mathbb{Z}$ as expected, in fact it's homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee S^1$.

More generally the problem is that $(X \times Y) / (X \times Z)$ is not $X \times (Y/Z)$.